# How to show that $X$ and $X_c$ have the same compact subsets, and the two induced topologies on these compact subsets are coincide?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the appendix of Algebraic Topology by A. Hatcher, at p.524, it is written that

> It is easy to see that X and $X_c$ have the same compact subsets, and the two induced topologies on these compact subsets coincide, where $X_c$ is the "compactly generated space" by a collection $\{X_{\alpha}\}$of compact subsets of X whose union is X.

I tried to prove it with some arguments on open coverings, but it didn't worked. I tried to search proofs, but everybody just says that it is easy or one can prove it. Could anyone show me a proof?

Comment: “A collection” ? Not the collection of *all* compact sets as the answerer seems to use?

Comment: That's right. It should be the collection of all compact subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $K$ is a compact subspace of $X_c,$ and let $\mathcal{U} = \{U_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $K$ in $X.$ As all open sets in $X$ are also open in $X_c,$ $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $K$ in $X_c.$ Since $K$ is compact in $X_c,$ there exists a finite subcover $\{U_{\alpha_1},\dots, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ of $K.$ But this finite subcover consists of opens in $X,$ so we have shown that $K$ is compact in $X.$

Conversely, if $K\subseteq X$ is compact, let $\mathcal{U} = \{U_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $K$ in $X_c.$ Now, each $U_\alpha$ may not be open in $X,$ but it is true that $U_\alpha\cap C$ is open in $C$ for all compact $C\subseteq X.$ In particular, $\mathcal{U}' = \{U_\alpha\cap K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ in $X_c$ as well. Now, for $U_\alpha\cap K$ to be open in $K$ means that $U_\alpha\cap K = V_\alpha$ for some open $V_\alpha\subseteq X.$ Thus, we have an open cover $\mathcal{V} = \{V_\alpha\}$ of $K$ by opens in $X$ which satisfies $V_\alpha\cap K = U_\alpha\cap K$ for all $\alpha.$ But since $K$ is compact in $X,$ there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{V}' = \{V_{\alpha_1},\dots,V_{\alpha_n}\}$ of $K.$ Since $V_\alpha\cap K = U_\alpha\cap K$ for all $\alpha,$ $\mathcal{U}' = \{U_{\alpha_1},\dots, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ is a finite subcover of $K$ in $X_c,$ so that $K$ is compact in $X_c.$

Recall that the induced topology on a compact set $K$ is the topology where $U\subseteq K$ is open if $U = V\cap K$ for some open in the larger space.

If $U\subseteq K$ is an open induced by $X_c,$ then $U$ is a subset of $X$ such that $U\cap C$ is open in $C$ for all compact $C\subseteq X.$ But in particular, this means that $U$ is open in $K,$ so that $U = V\cap K$ for some open $V\subseteq X.$ Hence, $U$ is also an open induced by $X.$

Conversely, if $U\subseteq K$ is an open induced by $X,$ then $U = V\cap K$ for some open $V\subseteq X.$ But if $V$ is open in $X,$ $V$ is open in $X_c,$ so that $U$ is also open in the induced topology on $K$ by $X_c.$ Hence, the induced topologies on compact subsets coincide.

Comment: Really appreciate for your reply. Could you please give me more details about the statement "$U_{\alpha} \cap C$  is open in $C$ for all compact $C \subset X$? Obviously it is true for the generators $X_{\alpha}$ but I am having trouble proving this for general compact subset $C$.

Comment: @penopen0 By Hatcher's definition, $X_c$ is the space generated by all compact subsets of $X.$ So, the $X_\alpha$ are in this case, precisely [all] the compact subsets of $X.$ He says "In case $\{X_\alpha\}$ is the collection of compact subsets of $X,$ we write $X_c$ for this new compactly generated topology."

Comment: OMG I misread the article... totally you are right. Thank you very much.